# java 8 stream do Operation1 on first item in category, then Operation2 on all items in the category

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a list of categories with a list of items contained in the categories

```
//Just example of structure:
List<Category> categories = getCategories();
List<Item> items = category.getItems();
```

With the Java streaming API how do you do Operation1() on first sub-item in a category, then Operation2() on all items in the category?

I want to do it in the cleanest code. So I try to do it in one stream, or what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: *I want to do it in the cleanest code. So I try to do it in one stream*: those statements are contradictory. You want two separate operations here. Do the first one, which doesn't need to do any iteration. The do the second one, which does need an iteration. Keep it stupid simple. Streams are not needed, even for the second operation.

Comment: Do you mean `getCategories().stream().map(Category::getItems).forEach()`?

Comment: What is getCategories() method used for?

It it provides categoriess. Then you could use something like getCategories().stream().map(Category::getItems).map(do the operation)

Comment: Read the question guys (except JB). He doesn't want to perform the same operation for everything.

Comment: @Frederik I rewrote `categories` to `category` in your question as I highly doubt you were trying to call a method `getItems()` on a java List. Feel free to revert if that was somehow your intention.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing that, this would do the trick:

```
List<Category> categories = getCategories();

categories.forEach(category -> {
    List<Item> items = category.getItems();
    IntStream.range(0, items.size()).forEach(i -> {
                Item item = items.get(i);
                if (i == 0)
                    operation1(item);
                operation2(item);
            }
    );
});
```

However, for general readability I would strongly recommend just getting the first element (if present) and doing your operation1 on it, and then iterating through the rest (whether by stream or not).

That said, if you would actually not have lists to begin with but have truly streaming and non-blocking code, there is something to say for this approach. This is also why I didn't add `.stream()` before the `.forEach` over categories, you're starting from a list to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no clean way to perform this, but the following code should do the trick. Using an `AtomicBoolean` to track whether the first element has been treated or not

```
List<Category> categories = getCategories();
List<Item> items = category.getItems();
AtomicBoolean bool = new AtomicBoolean(true);

items.forEach(item -> {
         if (bool.get()) {
             bool.set(false);
             operation1(item);
         }
         operation2(item);
     });
```